# DELETE DB2 using OPENQUERY returns error about key column insufficient

Tags: linked-server, db2-400

I am trying to delete rows on DB2 i Series using a link server but am getting an error message.
Key column information is insufficient or incorrect. Too many rows were affected by update

This is the query

```
DELETE FROM DB2
FROM OPENQUERY(TEST1, 'SELECT FIELD1 FROM LIBRARY1.FILE1') DB2
INNER JOIN #DLT_FILE1 DLT ON 
DB2.FIELD1 = DLT.FIELD1
```

There is one column in both temp file #DLT_FILE1 and DB2 table LIBRARY1.FILE1

Answer (score 2):

Db2 for IBM i (aka DB2-400) doesn't allow positioned deletes, ie from a cursor, that uses joins.

AMarc's suggestion might work, once you fix the syntax...I believe this is correct.

```
DELETE 
 FROM OPENQUERY(TEST1
               , 'SELECT FIELD1 FROM LIBRARY1.FILE1 DB2
                  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                FROM #DLT_FILE1 DLT 
                                WHERE DB2.FIELD1 = DLT.FIELD1)
                 ')
```